ORDS not start ORA-12504, TNS:listener was not given the SERVICE_NAME in CONNECT_DATA
I installed ORDS 24.2.3 with APEX 24.1 and oracle database 19c but when I start ords then it gives this error:
oracle.net.ns.NetException: Listener refused the connection with the following error:
ORA-12504, TNS:listener was not given the SERVICE_NAME in CONNECT_DATA
ServiceUnavailableException [statusCode=503, logLevel=SEVERE, reasons=[Maximum retry attempts to refresh connection pool named: default reached.
APEX is installed in PDB and I also configure ords with the same but not working.

Your ORDS pool config is using a service name that the listener for the database does not recognize.
Here's an example where the connection pool is configured using TNS

Find your configdir
Under the 'databases' directory, find your connection pool. If you only have 1, it will be called 'default.'
In there is a settings.xml file, look for the XML tags that start with
db.
If i go look at that tns file, i can see that the 'PDB' entry points to a database service called 'freepdb1'

If you're getting this error message, you need to make sure the listener will be ok with connection requests to 'freepdb1'

I talk about this in more detail on my blog.
